# Why does this command 'seq 6 | sed -n '0,/2/p' ' work in macosx?

Tags: linux, macos, sed

In MacOSX, why does this command perform differing from Linux? I want to test `sed` command with address `0,address2` and `1,address2`. but I found it performs differing between MacOSX and Linux? what's going on?
it's

```
seq 6 | sed -n '0,/2/p'
```

Comment: Provide a minimal,verifiable input and expected output? What is your requirement?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, `sed` is the GNU implementation, on OS X it's the BSD implementation. They have some different options, and some different behaviors.

Line numbers in `sed` start counting at `1`, not `0`, and if you change the command to `1,/2/p` the commands work the same.

Comment: I know "1,/2/p" works the same .but I saw a blog saying if you use '0,/2/p' ,the first address matches by default,then it will start match the second address.

Comment: That blogger probably only tried GNU sed, and didn't realize it was not portable.